# Can't retrieve a Stream List of map from cloud firestore for flutter using Getx Statemanagement [Updated]

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

I'm trying to retrieve a stream List of NewsModel from cloud firestore but ultimately failing. Codes and images are as follows.

I have a collection 'news' > document 'USA' > field list. // list is an array which contains list of map. I want to retrieve this list.

How can I retrieve data from firebase, store in the model object and use the model for UI?

Error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)
```

Code are as follow:

Model:

```
class NewsModel {
  String title, titleImage, brief;
  List aList;

  NewsModel({this.title, this.titleImage, this.brief, this.aList});

  factory NewsModel.fromMap(dynamic fieldData) {
    return NewsModel(
        title: fieldData['title'],
        titleImage: fieldData['titleImage'],
        brief: fieldData['brief'],
        aList: fieldData['mediaDescList']);
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  // onInit
  @override
  void onInit() {
    finalNewsModel.bindStream(streamDemo());
    fetchDocs();
    super.onInit();
  }

  //
  Rxn<List<NewsModel>> finalNewsModel = Rxn<List<NewsModel>>();

  //
  List<NewsModel> get newsModelList => finalNewsModel.value;

  //
  Stream<List<NewsModel>> streamDemo() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('news')
        .doc('USA')
        .snapshots()
        .map((ds) {
      var mapData = ds.data();
      List mapList = mapData['list'];
      List<NewsModel> newsModelList = [];
      mapList.forEach((element) {
        newsModelList.add(NewsModel.fromMap(element));
      });
      return newsModelList;
    });
  }
}
```

UI:

```
class HomeBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeBodyState createState() => _HomeBodyState();
}

class _HomeBodyState extends State<HomeBody> {

//
  final _controller = Get.put(Controller());

  //
  NewsModel _newsModel = NewsModel();

     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GetBuilder<Controller>(builder: (_controller) {
        if (_controller.newsModelList == null) {
          return Text('Loading');
        } else if (_controller.newsModelList.isEmpty) {
          return Text('Empty List');
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _controller.newsModelList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return MyContainer(
                title: _newsModel.title[index],
                titleImage: _newsModel.titleImage[index],
              );
            },
          );
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

**[image]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1:**

> The getter 'length' was called on null.

The error is coming from your null check below:

```dart
    if (_controller.newsModelList.length == null) {
      return Text('Loading');
    }
```

You're checking if the length of the list is `null` but the list itself is null so you're calling `.length` on `null`.
That's the reason the error says:

> The getter 'length' was called on null.

**Solution:**

You should rather check if the list itself is null like below:

```dart
    if (_controller.newsModelList == null) {
      return Text('Loading');
    }
```

Now if you want to check if the list is empty, you have to first ensure the list is not `null`, then you can call `.isEmpty()` on the list.

You can then add your existing else statement to show the list of `MyContainer` widgets.

**Error 2:**

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
> The method '[]' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling:

This error is because you're trying to get a value of a null object.
And it occurs in the lines below:

```dart
    title: _newsModel.title[index],
    titleImage: _newsModel.titleImage[index],
```

This is because `_newsModel.title` and `_newsModel.titleImage` is null since you created the `_newsModel` object without supplying the parameters.

**Solution:**

The solution will be to delete this line below from your `build` method:

```dart
      NewsModel _newsModel = NewsModel();
```

Then you can get your `_newModel` variable from the `_controller.newsModelList` list.

Your new UI code containing both solutions should be updated to the code block below:

```dart
    class HomeBody extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeBodyState createState() => _HomeBodyState();
    }
    
    class _HomeBodyState extends State<HomeBody> {
    
    //
      final _controller = Get.put(Controller());
    
         @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Obx(() {
        if (_controller.newsModelList == null) {
          return Text('Loading');
        } else if (_controller.newsModelList.isEmpty) {
          return Text('Empty List');
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _controller.newsModelList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final NewsModel _newsModel = _controller.newsModelList[index];
              return MyContainer(
                title: _newsModel.title,
                titleImage: _newsModel.titleImage,
                index: index,
              );
            },
          );
        }
      }),
        );
      }
```

Comment: Hello Victor, Thank you for the response. Your solution did eliminate the null error but yet I'm getting the 2nd error. I have updated the question. Please checkout. I'm waiting for your response.

Comment: Going through now.

Comment: Hello @RajA, I've updated the answer with the fix for the second error. Please check it out.

Comment: Hello @Victor, I'm so grateful for your efforts and support. Your solution did work. I did so minor edits like removing the [index] from fields and wrapping it with Obx() as Getbuilder wasn't updating the stream. Excellent support and explaination. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to know it worked! Thanks for the edit.

Comment: The stream is not updating when the document Id is changed dynamically. Can you please review this issue ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67660041/stream-not-updating-when-docid-is-changed-dynamically-flutter-firebase-getx

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize a value to Rxn

```
Rxn<List<NewsModel>> finalNewsModel = Rxn<List<NewsModel>>([]);

  //change stream like this
 Stream<List<NewsModel>> streamDemo() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('news')
        .doc('USA')
        .snapshots()
        .map((ds) {
         var mapData = ds.data();
  List mapList = mapData['list'];
  List<NewsModel> newsModelList = [];
  mapList.forEach((element) {
    newsModelList.add(NewsModel.fromMap(element));
  });
  return newsModelList;
    });
  }
```

Use GetX builder or Obx

```
class HomeBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeBodyState createState() => _HomeBodyState();
}

class _HomeBodyState extends State<HomeBody> {

//
  final Controller _controller = Get.put<Controller>(Controller());

  //
 

     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Obx((){
        if (_controller.newsModelList == null) {
          return Text('Loading');
        } else if (_controller.newsModelList.isEmpty) {
          return Text('Empty List');
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _controller.newsModelList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return MyContainer(
                title: _newsModel.title[index],
                titleImage: _newsModel.titleImage[index],
              );
            },
          );
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```